# Show records on userInput store PROCEDURE

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I want to show records based on user input.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ShowRecords]
        @recordsToShow int
    AS
    BEGIN
    select top @recordsToShow * from usermaster
    END
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Cool, what's your problem?

Comment: Declare @Percentage AS int = 5
SELECT TOP (@Percentage)   * FROM tablename

Answer (score 0):

You should pass parameters [which is user input] inside of the stored procedure. check the following snippets:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ShowRecords](@parameter int/tinyint)
AS
BEGIN
    select top (@parameter) * from [Table_name];
END
```

-- parameter type should be numeric;

Answer (score 0):

In sql server (actually any sql) you need to build a sql statement and execute it. For example given

```
user_id     contact_type_id value                status dt
----------- --------------- -------------------- ------ -----------------------
1           2               bbb                  1      NULL
2           1               example@mail.com     NULL   NULL
4           1               example2@mail.com    NULL   NULL
5           2               123345               NULL   NULL
6           3               skypeLogin2          NULL   NULL

(5 row(s) affected) 

CREATE PROCEDURE P
        @recordsToShow int
    AS
    BEGIN
    declare @sqlstmt Nvarchar(1000)
    set @sqlstmt = concat('select top ',@recordstoshow,' * from users order by user_id desc')

    EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL  @SQLSTMT
    END
GO
EXEC P 3

user_id     contact_type_id value                status dt
----------- --------------- -------------------- ------ -----------------------
6           3               skypeLogin2          NULL   NULL
5           2               123345               NULL   NULL
4           1               example2@mail.com    NULL   NULL

(3 row(s) affected)
```

BTW top without an order by is pretty meaningless.